# inflection point for 3-parameter weibull in R?

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, weibull, drc

The `drc` package in R contains self-starting functions to fit a 3-parameter Weibull model to data. The package gives 2 parameterizations of the 3-parameter weibull (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/drc.pdf):

```
f(x) = 0 + (d − 0) exp(− exp(b(log(x) − log(e))))
f(x) = 0 + (d − 0)(1 − exp(− exp(b(log(x) − log(e)))))
```

Documentation for the package suggests that `d` represents the upper asymptote, `b` is the rate parameter, and that the curve has an inflection point at dose `e`. However, plotting these functions and using R to solve for when the 2nd derivative = 0 gives a value different than `e` for the inflection point. For example:

```
dd=1
bb = -5
ee = 30
curve(dd*exp(-exp(bb * (log(x) - log(ee))) ) , xlim=c(0,100))
abline(v=ee)

# 1st deriv
g <- function(x) {}
body(g) <- D( expression(dd*exp(-exp(bb * (log(x) - log(ee))) )), "x")
curve(g, xlim=c(0, 100))
abline(v=ee)

# 2nd deriv
g <- function(x) {}
body(g) <- D(D( expression(dd*exp(-exp(bb * (log(x) - log(ee))) )), "x"), "x")
curve(g, xlim=c(0, 100))
abline(v=ee)

uniroot(g, c(20,50))  # should be 30, but is not?
```

Is the documentation incorrect? Or does this have to do with the particular logged parameterization of the weibull (that constrains it to be positive)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation is wrong.

`exp(-exp(x))` has an inflection point at 0:

```
DD <- function(expr, name, order = 1) {
  if(order < 1) stop("'order' must be >= 1")
  if(order == 1) D(expr, name)
  else DD(D(expr, name), name, order - 1)
}

DD( expression(exp(-exp(x))) , "x" , 2)
#-(exp(-exp(x)) * exp(x) - exp(-exp(x)) * exp(x) * exp(x))
```

`exp(0)` equals 1. Thus, we have:
-(1/e - 1*e) = 0

I can see how one could then assume that `exp(-exp(log(x) - log(c)))` would also have an inflection point when the argument of the inner exponential gets zero. Bbut that's just not the case because the `log` changes the curvature and the second derivative:

```
DD( expression(exp(-exp(log(x) - log(c)))) , "x" , 2)
#-(exp(-exp(log(x) - log(c))) * (exp(log(x) - log(c)) * (1/x) * 
#    (1/x) - exp(log(x) - log(c)) * (1/x^2)) - exp(-exp(log(x) - 
#    log(c))) * (exp(log(x) - log(c)) * (1/x)) * (exp(log(x) - 
#    log(c)) * (1/x)))
```

If we put x = c, we have:

> -(1/e * (1 * 1/c * 1/c - 1 * 1/c^2) - 1/e * 1 * 1/c * 1 * 1/c)
>
> = -(0 - 1/e * 1/c^2)
>
> = 1/e * 1/c^2

And that is not 0.

Just to check my maths:

```
g <- function(x) {}
body(g) <- DD( expression(exp(-exp(log(x) - log(c)))) , "x" , 2)
c <- 2
g(2)
#[1] 0.09196986
1/exp(1) * 1/2^2
#[1] 0.09196986
```

(For extra credit you should do the second derivative by hand. I don't have that much time.)

Comment: That is a nice way to confirm my suspicion. Is it clear to you what the `c` parameter represents? It does clearly shift the curve along the x-axis. Or maybe this is a mischaracterization of the Weibull function all together?